# Laravel eloquent not getting data when i use with()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

Sorry for bad englis guys ((
I have 2 tables (products and product_bids). When loading product_bids tables, i need to get its products which were created before the bid itself.

```
return ProductBid::whereId('7')->first()->product_created;
```

when i use this code, its getting the product.

```
return ProductBid::with('product_created')->get();
```

But when i use this code, its not getting products

Here's the eloquent in ProductBid Model:

```
public function product_created()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id')
        ->whereBetween('products.start_time', [ '2000-10-10', $this->start_time ]);
}
```

I think ($this->start_time) not working while getting data. Because when i type custom date manually, its getting products. But when i use $this->start_time, i am getting null.

Comment: `$this` in this context does not refer to a specific model instance because it needs to run for all results in the result set (even if your filter in this particular case happesn to return only one). You should consider using a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes) after you get the result

Comment: if you really need to get `product_created` relationship then you need to use Eager Loading. try this way `foreach ($proBids as $product) {  var_dump($product->product_created); }`   read this one https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Is start_time a field in the product_bids table?

Comment: yes, both tables has start_time field @KevinBui